# How to extract a query from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my database (I put only the important cols)

**CATEGORIES(cid, cname)**

RECORD CATEGORIES

```
(1, A)
(2, B)
(3, C)
```

**USERS(uid, uname, cid);**

RECORD USERS

```
(1, JON, 1)
(2, NED, 1)
(3, ROB, 2)
(4, JAM, 3)
(5, TYR, 1)
(6, CAT, 2)
(7, JOF, 2)
(8, SAN, 3)
(9, ARY, 1)
```

**PURCHASES(pid, uid, price)**

RECORD PURCHASES

```
(1, 2, 100)
(2, 5, 150)
(3, 1, 300)
(4, 2, 120)
(5, 3, 50)
(6, 3, 210)
(7, 2, 190)
(8, 8, 155)
(9, 9, 111)
(10, 2, 100)
(11, 2, 150)
(12, 1, 310)
(13, 8, 120)
(14, 3, 50)
(15, 7, 210)
(16, 2, 190)
(17, 6, 155)
(18, 4, 111)
```

I want a final table:

```
FINAL TABLE (cname, total)
```

total is: sum of maximum 3 values of tnum group by SECOND.sid.

These are 3 maximum values for each SECOND row that you can get by SELECT FROM table THIRD.

```
1 -> MAX(300, 310) = 310
2 -> MAX(100, 120, 190, 100, 150, 190) = 190
3 -> MAX(210, 50, 50) = 210
4 -> MAX(111) = 111
5 -> MAX(150) = 150
6 -> MAX(155) = 155
7 -> MAX(210) = 210
8 -> MAX(155, 120) = 155
9 -> MAX(111) = 111
```

**Category A have user 1, 2, 5 and 9 so ONLY THE MAXIMUM THREE max will be sum**

```
total1(310) > total2(190) > total5(150) > total9(111).
```

So

```
A -> total1(310) + total2(190) + total5(150) = 650
```

Category B have user 3, 6 and 7 so all these three are right:

```
B -> total3(210) + total6(155) + total7(210) = 575
```

Finally category C have user 4 and 8

```
C-> total4(111) + total8(155) = 266**
```

So I did this subquery:

```
SELECT max(price) tot, u.uid user, p.pid purchase, u.cid category 
FROM purchase p, user u 
WHERE p.uid=u.uid group by user ORDER BY tot DESC LIMIT 3
```

Limit 3 doesn't work because print the first three values.

This is the total query:

```
SELECT c.cname, sum(totalmax.tot) totalsum

FROM purchases p1, categories c1, users u1, 

(SELECT max(price) tot, u.uid user, p.pid purchase, u.cid category 
FROM purchase p, user u 
WHERE p.uid=u.uid group by user ORDER BY tot DESC LIMIT 3) totalmax

WHERE totalmax.pid = p1.pid AND u1.cid=c1.cid AND u1.uid=p1.uid

GROUP BY c1.cnome

ORDER BY totalsum DESC
```

I tried to do this (that is the think that I want):

```
AND u.cid = c1.cid
```

But the subquery not read f1.fid.
How can I give c1.cid to the subquery?

Thanks for answer

Comment: Are you really using both MySQL and SQL Server here? I spy some product specific SQL that won't run on both products...

Comment: No sqlserver. I made a mistake with tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you edited the question, I edited this answer. The query you are looking for is not straight forward because of the "top N in group" selection you need.

This is my quick attempt, which surely is not optimal (suggestions welcome).

```
select cname, sum(maxp) from(
    (select * from
        (select c.cname, p.uid, max(price) maxp from purchases p left join users u left join categories c on u.cid = c.cid on p.uid = u.uid group by p.uid) x
    where x.cname='A' order by maxp desc limit 3)

union all

    (select * from
        (select c.cname, p.uid, max(price) maxp from purchases p left join users u left join categories c on u.cid = c.cid on p.uid = u.uid group by p.uid) x
    where x.cname='B' order by maxp desc limit 3)

union all

    (select * from
        (select c.cname, p.uid, max(price) maxp from purchases p left join users u left join categories c on u.cid = c.cid on p.uid = u.uid group by p.uid) x
    where x.cname='C' order by maxp desc limit 3)
    ) y

group by cname order by cname
```

Comment: This query give the same screen of mine. Surely is better because I'm not expert with JOIN.

Comment: The problem is that I want that in subquery there are the maximum three max values for each t1.fid. Do you understand?

Comment: oh, sorry, I misread you question. I can edit the answer but first I need to understand better what you want to achieve. You want to start from table THREE, consider the 3 highest records (by tnum) for each sid and then... ?

Comment: I saw that you are italian. If you want I can explain you better in italian. However I want that max(tnum) is of the three max values for each f.fid. Do you understand?

Comment: Try writing a comment in Italian if you can explain the situation better, because I still did not get the full picture.

Comment: max(tnum) extract the maximum value for each id of table SECOND. Then I want that sum(val) will be of the maximum values of three id of table SECOND. I'm sorry for english but it is no legal to write in italian here. If you want this is my email gringogringo@live.it

Comment: I have edited the question. Now I think that is clearer than before

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. As you can image I haven't only three Categories (I put only A, B and C to be easier to understand) but I have more than 60. Probably I have to build the query with PHP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * INTO #values FROM
(SELECT sid, max(tnum) as val
FROM THIRD t
GROUP BY sid) v

SELECT f.fname, sum(val)
FROM
FIRST f
INNER JOIN SECOND s
ON f.fid= s.fid
INNER JOIN #values v
ON v.sid=s.sid
GROUP BY f.fname

DROP TABLE #values
```

Comment: I use mysql. What is SELECT * INTO? I use it only in PLSQL

Comment: Can you create a temp table in mysql? I came here after reading sql-server and wrote a CTE first, and when u edited tags I removed with clause.

Comment: temp-table: `create temporary table tmp_values select ...`

Comment: The temporary table give me an error. I try to use the first in the inner JOIN. It work like me. The problem is that the sub query does not get the first three values for each